# Choosing file by clicking on a button [Python 2.7.6]

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm trying to create a simple button that allows me to choose files such as text doc/pictures(jpg/png). I tried searching for answers here but didn't had any luck. I'm using Tkinter for my GUI interface.

This are my codes so far.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Hashing Tool")
root.geometry("600x300")

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )
button = Button(frame, text="Choose File", fg="black")
button.pack( side = BOTTOM)

from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
filename = askopenfilename() 
print(filename)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So, what is you question / problem?

Comment: well , I managed to code the open file dialog but I wanted it to be whereby the users can click on the "choose File" button before the open file dialog pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you ask for a file as soon as the program starts. You have to put that part of the code into a callback function and pass that to the button's `command` parameter.

```
def getfile():
    filename = askopenfilename() 
    print(filename)

button = Button(frame, text="Choose File", fg="black", command=getfile)
```

Comment: thanks for the help. However, I'm still facing some problems after amending the code. The interface appears but there is no button appearing at all when I tried to run it.

Comment: @JoanT Works fine for me. What exactly did you do? Just more the two `filename`-lines to the method and replace the `button = ` line.